# Jquery - .toFixed(2) fixed number reduce to 3 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-calculation

I have the following code that works with the exception of limiting the `#result2` to `3 digits`

```
current #result2: input 1 and you get 0.010416666666666666

needed #result2: input 1 and get 0.01
```

I need to limit the result to `0.00 2 digits` after so that it is not a long result.

This is going to be used to convert pixels to inches for designers as part of a pet project.

** What would be really great is if the result would actually convert to inches, 
example: input 1 and get back 1/8 but not sure if that can be done???

Here is the Html:

```
<label>Pixels</label>
<input class="calcd" id="calc3" type="text" />
<input class="calcd" id="calc4" type="hidden" value="96" />
<p>Inches</p><span id="result2"></span>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".calcd").keyup(function(){

        var val1 = parseInt($("#calc3").val());
        var val2 = parseInt($("#calc4").val());

        if ( ! isNaN(val1) && ! isNaN(val2))
        {
             $("#result2").text(val1 / val2).toFixed(3);
        }
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZdJL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#result2").text(val1 / val2).toFixed(3);
```

There's your problem. You want to call `toFixed(3)` on the value *before* you pass it to `text()`.

```
$("#result2").text((val1 / val2).toFixed(3));
```

It may be useful to step through with a debugger at times like this, to see where expressions are evaluated and how it works.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That worked perfectly. It never fails. Long day = missing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Basically toFixed convert the **number into string** and apply only on String.
> 2. Get the values in different variables and store the result in variable and apply toFixed.

```
var val1 = parseInt($("#calc3").val());
var val2 = parseInt($("#calc4").val());

var result = (val1 / val2).toFixed(3);
```

> 2.Store the value in textbox.

```
$("#result2").text(result);
```

> OR

```
 $("#result2").val(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 digits as Int not work for fixed, if you use parseFloat().toFixed() works as a charm! and is cleaner if you ask me!